# Segmentation of 2D vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Currently I have a 2D vector, containing 600 values "blocks" with 2 values in each block. 
What I want to do is, create a new vector of vectors that segments the blocks, so instead of the values stored being 2, I will therefore store 10 or any given number of blocks that will allow me to.

Here is an example, using a small vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > values = { {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {5, 8}, {4, 5} };
```

This can be segmented therefore into 2, and, which block will therefore contain 4 blocks. E.g.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > values2 = { {1, 2, 2, 4}, {5, 8, 4, 5} };
```

There is now two blocks within the vector of vectors and each of these blocks now contain 4 values.

But how would this be possible? I'm only use to segmenting 1D vectors, so for this task, would using `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter` be efficient for solving this? In the actual problem, I have 600 blocks containing 2 values in each.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't sound very hard, have you tried yet? It sounds like about 4 lines of code. It's even easier if you flatten the first vector first, but that is unnecessary. I personally wouldn't bother trying to use std::copy or std::back_inserter, just write a loop.

Comment: @Salgar But would I need a variable in place, let's say `1) iterate through the entire number of vectors 2) check if the value is less 4 3) push that vector to the new 2D vector`? The concept seems really fuzzy to me

Comment: @Salgar can you please show these about 4 lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code for your simplified example. I hope it will help or at least show the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>>::size_type size_type;
    const size_type N = 4;


    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v1 = { {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {5, 8}, {4, 5}, { 7, 8 } };

    for ( const auto &v : v1 )
    {
        for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_type n = 
        std::accumulate( v1.begin(), v1.end(), size_type( 0 ),
                         [] ( size_type acc, const std::vector<double> &v )
                         {
                            return ( acc + v.size() );
                         } );

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v2( ( n + N - 1 ) / N );

    std::cout << "v2.size() = " << v2.size() << std::endl;

    auto it = v1.begin();

    for ( std::vector<double> &v : v2 )
    {
        for ( size_type i = 0; i < N / 2 && it != v1.end(); ++it, ++i )
        {
            v.insert( v.end(), ( *it ).begin(), ( *it ).end() );
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &v : v2 )
    {
        for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 
2 4 
5 8 
4 5 
7 8 

v2.size() = 3
1 2 2 4 
5 8 4 5 
7 8
```

If your compiler does not support C++ 11 then this range based for

```
    auto it = v1.begin();

    for ( std::vector<double> &v : v2 )
    {
        for ( size_type i = 0; i < N / 2 && it != v1.end(); ++it, ++i )
        {
            v.insert( v.end(), ( *it ).begin(), ( *it ).end() );
        }
    }
```

can be substituted for

```
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>>::iterator iterator;

    iterator it1 = v1.begin();

    for ( iterator it2 = v2.begin(); it2 != v2.end(); ++it2 )
    {
        for ( size_type i = 0; i < N / 2 && it1 != v1.end(); ++it1, ++i )
        {
            ( *it2 ).insert( ( *it2 ).end(), ( *it1 ).begin(), ( *it1 ).end() );
        }
    }
```

By the way it is the case when it is better to use the range based for instead of a standard algorithm.:)

For example

```
size_type n = 0;
for ( const auto &v : v1 ) n += v.size();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. This does make sense, however, I'm not allowed to use C++11 because of the standards that I'm using. I will try and code a solution from this though

Comment: @user1326876 You can substitute the range based for for an ordinary for loop and initialize your vector using push_back. It is not proncipally.
You can test my code at www.ideone.com selecting language C++11

Comment: Sorry. I'm finding it difficult to understand how the methods you applied in your post, would be computed using none c++11 techniques. Any chance you could provide a bit more descriptive or an example?

Comment: You sir, are the wizard of the month. Thank you so much, I have been stressing about this for so long! :) Thanks!!